# Ayuda con polimorfismo

Tags: java

Hola buenas tengo un ejercicio de **Polimorfismo** donde no comprendo bien lo que esta pasando. La primera y la tercera llamada la entiendo, a un `Top` le entra un `Top` pero el resto no veo lo que esta pasando.

El resultado siempre es B.

```
public class Top {
    public void m( Top p) {System.out.println("B");}
    public void m( Bottom p) {System.out.println("c");}
}
public class Middle extends Top {
    public void m(Bottom p ) {System.out.println("K");}
}

public class Bottom extends Middle {
    public void m(Middle p ) {System.out.println("W");}
    public void m(Bottom p ) {System.out.println("X");}
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        run();
    }
    public static void run() {
        Top tm = new Middle();
        Top tb= new Bottom();
        Middle mb = new Bottom();
        tm.m(tb);
        tm.m(mb);
        tb.m(tm);
        tb.m(mb);
        mb.m(new Middle());
        new Bottom().m(tb);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando tienes varios métodos con el mismo nombre que son compatibles con la llamada, el más específico es el elegido. Pero esta elección *es en tiempo de compilación*, no de ejecución, por tanto no importa el valor real de la variable sino el tipo declarado.

Puesto que tus variables son de tipo `Top`, da igual si realmente apuntan a instancias de `Middle` o `Bottom`, el compilador asigna la llamada al método declarado como

```
public void m( Top p) {System.out.println("B");}
```